# Do I have to uninstall Office 2013 before I install Office 365?

Tags: microsoft-office, office365

On our company we have about 100 computers with Office 2013 (Volume Licenses)
Now we have bought a subscription of Office 365 Midsize. Do we have to uninstall Office 2013 before installing Office 365 on the portal on every machine or what is the difference?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't have to.  But your users will get confused by which version of Office they should be using.

Answer (score 1):

Ms Office 365 and Ms Office 2013 are two different things so you can keep 2013 and install 365 on top of it. It makes no difference but I would recommend uninstalling as the default programs would be confusing

Answer (score 0):

You can install both as the same time and both will work. If you want your users to only use Office 365 I'd suggest uninstalling Office 2013 beforehand instead of after installing Office 365.